# Get CSV data between XML tags in java Stax

Tags: java, xml

I am having trouble with acquiring some csv text data between xml tags using stax. When I try to read the data between tags I get extra newline characters added in sporadically:

I have a XML file containing, among other things, a number of csv sections which I am trying to import into a java program. Specifically, for the XML file containing:

```
<layer name="Foreground" width="10" height="5">
   <data encoding="csv">
      0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,6,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,
      0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
  </data>
</layer>
```

I am trying to import the csv data into an array (or at least a String, and I can go from there.) When I try to read in the data via an event reader

```
if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart() == "data")
{
    System.out.println("Parsing Data for Layer " + layerCounter);
    while (attributes.hasNext())
    {
        Attribute attribute = attributes.next(); 
        switch (attribute.getName().toString())
        {
            case ("encoding"):
                System.out.println("\tEncoding = " + attribute.getValue());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    event = eventReader.nextEvent();
    while(!event.isEndElement())
    {                            
        System.out.println(event.asCharacters().getData());
        event = eventReader.nextEvent();
    }
    layerCounter++;
}
```

This almost does what I'm trying but I get extra newline characters in the output. For the above file, I get:

```
Parsing Data for Layer 1
        Encoding = csv

0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,6,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,

0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I am wondering if anyone might know what's going on here.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around XML parsing and there is probably a better way to get this data in its pure format. Alternatively, I could write the XML file to store the data as XML tags themselves, but thought that the csv format was more convenient.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: change the character encoding of the file (with notepad or whatever), maybe there are some hidden '\n' or '\r'

Comment: Nothing in xml would do that, text editor might, copy and paste from one window to another more than possible.

Comment: Yes, as suggested, the program generating the csv's was sneaking in new-line characters every once and a while.
Thanks for the suggestions!